# Binomial Distribution Proof

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

What is that $I(\cdot)$ in the 3rd step means?

$p_{x_n}(y_n-y_{n-1}) = p(X_n=y_n-y_{n-1}) = p(X_n)$ belongs to the interval $\{0,1\}$, since it is a random variable. Then, how are getting to that $I$? A bit of clarification on the convolution formula might be of help.

[image]

Comment: What are the random variables $X_n,Y_{n-1}$? How are they distributed? Are they independent? Also, the equation is hard to read, it's best if you converted it to LaTeX.

Comment: It's an image, directly from the site.

Answer (score 1):

The function $I(\varphi)$, for some predicate $\varphi$, equals $1$ if $\varphi$ is true and $0$ otherwise. Hopefully now you can try to understand the rest of the expression on your own.

Comment: What is that function called?

And if it is 1, then the result comes to (n-1)!/(y<sub>n-1</sub>)!(n-y<sub>n-1</sub>)!

Comment: It's the indicator function of the predicate $\varphi$. It has lots of other notations, in fact I've never seen this particular one.

Comment: I understood the indicator function but how does it actually lead to the result? Please a little more clarification might help me. I still could not get to the answer.